# Metro Application connects to SQL via WCF Service - Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5, wcf-data-services

I have created a new metro application for Windows 8.

My intention was to consume data from the WCF data service in the metro application. The WCF service should connect to a SQL server installed on the local machine.

I have set up an Interface for my service so I can pass parameters to the methods I want the WCF to execute and then return results back to the Metro Application afterwards.

I followed a few different tutorials online and had success, until...

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have a included the code from both the Login landing Page and the SQL configuration page. When the metro application launches, it runs a method to check if there is a connection. If no connection is found it displays the SQL configuration page.

The application launches. OnNavigate to the login form the CheckConnection() method returns true. But when I enter user details and press login I simply get an error on the following line of code in the async void Login() method on the Login Page

```
newCustomType = await dataServiceClientName.CheckLoginAsync(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

If anyone understands why this error is displaying the help would be greatly appreciated.

I have included the relevant code (or what I can tell is relevant) below.

Thanks in advance :)

## Code Snippets:

### Abridged Service Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface CTUServiceInterface
{
    // TODO: Add your service operations here
    //LoginForm
    [OperationContract]
    bool CheckConnection();
    //SQL Config
    [OperationContract]
    bool UpdateConnectionDetails(string ConnectionString);
    //LoginForm
    [OperationContract]
    LoginDetails CheckLogin(string Username, string Password);
    //LoginForm Success
    [OperationContract]
    UserGlobalDetails GetActiveUserDetails(int UserKey);
    }
    
[DataContract]
public class LoginDetails
{
    bool loginSuccess = false;
    string errorMessage = "";
    int userKey = -1;

    [DataMember]
    public bool LoginSuccess
    {
        get { return loginSuccess; }
        set { loginSuccess = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return errorMessage; }
        set { errorMessage = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserKey
    {
        get { return userKey; }
        set { userKey = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class UserGlobalDetails
{
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";
    int departmentKey = -1;
    bool manager = false;

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int DepartmentKey
    {
        get { return departmentKey; }
        set { departmentKey = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Manager
    {
        get { return manager; }
        set { manager = value; }
    }
}
```

### Abridged Service Code

```
public class CTUService : CTUServiceInterface
{
    private static SqlConnection localConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-VIRTUAL;Initial Catalog=CarTraUnl;Integrated Security=True");

    //LoginForm
    public bool CheckConnection()
    {
        bool result = true;
        try
        {
            localConnection.Open();
            localConnection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }


    //SQL Config
    public bool UpdateConnectionDetails(string ConnectionString)
    {
        localConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        return CheckConnection();
    }


    //LoginForm
    public LoginDetails CheckLogin(string Username, string Password)
    {
        //Initilize the LoginDetails Object to return with results
        LoginDetails localDetails = new LoginDetails();
        //Initilize the localDataTable to hold sql results
        DataTable localDataTable = new DataTable("localDataTable");
        //Setup a SqlDataAdapter and get info from the 'UserGlobal' Table
        localConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter localDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "SELECT [Password],[Key]" +
            "FROM [CarTraUnl].[dbo].[UserGlobal]" +
            "WHERE [Username] = '" + Username + "'"
            , localConnection);
        localConnection.Close();
        //Fill localDataTable with information from the UserGlobal Table
        localDataAdapter.Fill(localDataTable);
        //Set loginStatus equal to the number of passwords found for the given username
        int loginStatus = localDataTable.Rows.Count;
        //If no passwords are found, there was no username like the given one
        if (loginStatus == 0)
        {
            localDetails.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Username";
        }
        //If one password was found, check if it matches the given password
        else if (loginStatus == 1 && localDataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == Password)
        {
            localDetails.LoginSuccess = true;
            localDetails.ErrorMessage = "";
            localDetails.UserKey = int.Parse(localDataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        }
        //If one password is found, but it doesn't match show the error
        else if (loginStatus == 1 && localDataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() != Password)
        {
            localDetails.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password";
        }
        //If multiple passwords are found, there are duplicate usernames
        else if (loginStatus > 1)
        {
            localDetails.ErrorMessage = "Duplicate Usernames";
        }
        return localDetails;
    }


    //LoginForm Success
    public UserGlobalDetails GetActiveUserDetails(int UserKey)
    {
        //Initilize UserGlobalDetails object to return later
        UserGlobalDetails localUserGlobalDetails = new UserGlobalDetails();
        //Initilize a DataTable to hold our sql results
        DataTable localDataTable = new DataTable("localDataTable");
        //Setup a SqlDataAdapter and get info from the 'UserGlobal' Table
        SqlDataAdapter localDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "SELECT [FirstName],[LastName],[DepartmentKey],[Manager]" +
            "FROM [CarTraUnl].[dbo].[UserGlobal]" +
            "WHERE [Key] = '" + UserKey + "'"
            , localConnection);
        //Fill localDataTable with information from the 'UserGlobal' Table
        localDataAdapter.Fill(localDataTable);

        //Configure the UserGlobalDetails object 'localUserGlobalDetails' with the retrived results
        localUserGlobalDetails.FirstName = localDataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        localUserGlobalDetails.LastName = localDataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        localUserGlobalDetails.DepartmentKey = int.Parse(localDataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString());
        localUserGlobalDetails.Manager = bool.Parse(localDataTable.Rows[0][3].ToString());

        //return the results
        return localUserGlobalDetails;
    }
   }
```

### Login.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        lblError.Text = "";
    }

    private async void CheckConnection()
    {
        CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient dataServiceClientName = new CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient();
        bool result = await dataServiceClientName.CheckConnectionAsync();
        if (result == false)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SqlConfig));
        }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Login();
    }

    private async void Login()
    {
        btnLogin.IsEnabled = false;
        CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient dataServiceClientName = new CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient();
        CTUServiceReference.LoginDetails newCustomType = new CTUServiceReference.LoginDetails();
        newCustomType = await dataServiceClientName.CheckLoginAsync(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        CTUServiceReference.UserGlobalDetails currentActiveUserDetails = new CTUServiceReference.UserGlobalDetails();
        currentActiveUserDetails = await dataServiceClientName.GetActiveUserDetailsAsync(newCustomType.UserKey);
        //The globalSettings.cs file is not included, but it just holds persistent application data
        globalSettings.currentUserKey = newCustomType.UserKey;
        globalSettings.firstName = currentActiveUserDetails.FirstName;
        globalSettings.lastName = currentActiveUserDetails.LastName;
        globalSettings.departmentKey = currentActiveUserDetails.DepartmentKey;
        globalSettings.manager = currentActiveUserDetails.Manager;

        if (newCustomType.LoginSuccess)
        {
            //This page is where we go when login is successful
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FormSelector));
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = newCustomType.ErrorMessage;
            btnLogin.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

### SQLConfig.xaml.cs

```
        private void btnSqlConfigSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        saveConfig();
    }

    private async void saveConfig()
    {
        btnSave.IsEnabled = false;
        string connectionstring = "";
        if (rbAutomatic.IsChecked == true)
        {
            //Integrated Secturity
            connectionstring = "Data Source=" + txtServer.Text + ";Initial Catalog= " + txtDB.Text + ";Integrated Security=True";
        }
        else
        {
            //Standard Authentication with username and password
            connectionstring = "Data Source=" + txtServer.Text + ";Initial Catalog= " + txtDB.Text + ";User Id=" + txtUser.Text + ";Password=" + txtPass.Text;
        }
        CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient dataServiceClientName = new CTUServiceReference.CTUServiceInterfaceClient();
        bool result = await dataServiceClientName.UpdateConnectionDetailsAsync(connectionstring);
        if (result)
        {
            this.Frame.GoBack();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Config error";
            btnSave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

## Version Info

#### Visual Studio

- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
- Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709
- Installed Version: Ultimate

#### SQL Server

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 11.0.2100.60
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 11.0.2100.60
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 6.2.9200.16384
- Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 6.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework - 4.0.30319.18051
- Operating System - 6.2.9200

Comment: Is there no one who could help?

Answer (score 0):

This error could have several causes but it means what it means... being, your service cannot access to:

```
"Data Source=" + txtServer.Text + ";
```

This is most probably not a problem in your code, but an SQLServer configuration issue.

I suggest you try the connectionString in an ODBC call first to see if you can access it like this from local and remote.

it seems like your services tries to connect via named pipes check in the SQLServer Configuration Manager to see if the protocol is started for your specific instance.

Also try to enable the TCP/IP protocol and check that it listens on the right port (1433).

It could also be you are not targeting the "Named Instance". ie:

```
"Data Source=MYSERVER"
```

instead of

```
"Data Source=MYSERVER\MyInstance"
```

hope this helps!